# Check user.is_active in all views

Tags: python, django

I have many views and in most of them I need check, if the user **is_active**:

```
if request.user.is_active:
    pass # some actions
else:
    #user.logout
```

How can it be shorten? I use **@login_required** (Django 1.6.2). If I change through admin user active = no, I can do any actions in profile (is_active returns **False**) like a normal user. But I need `reverse`: user with is_active **False** cant do anything, for example, they automaticaly logout.

How to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import user_passes_test

@user_passes_test(lambda u: u.is_active)
def my_view(request):
    # blah
```

Comment: it redirects on login page, is it possible redirects to `LOGOUT_URL`?

Comment: @tim You might want to write your own decorator. Just use `user_passes_test` as an inspiration.

Comment: I use `lambda u: u.is_active, login_url=settings.LOGOUT_URL`, but it doesnt works on change password and passwor reset urls